# Jasper report split type

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am using jasper report to export my reports to word document. On the detail section I have sub report. I have a problem with band split type. When I choose split type **stretch** or **immediate**  I got the below problem.

[image]

When I choose **Prevent** split type I don't get this error but this time there are lots of white space at the bottom of page if row space more than remain band height. How can I split my data partially at the bottom of page without border layout error?

sample code. just copy and paste any jasper studio editor and enter long text(at least fill two page) when prompting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2016-09-27T22:00:51 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f86bcfb7-d774-451f-9f46-c58f57e0efbb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from dummy]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="sno" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="filed1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="filed2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="0cd17b54-755c-42fe-9363-7266a24337e3"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="f216b782-3080-4ba8-8cc3-2609c684f4be"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[filed1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="71985024-8b9a-49ae-81e0-6d6e9335cec7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[filed2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="d45c0977-d842-424b-ab44-7edd5672b72d"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[Image]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="fb93f1ac-7f7a-48fe-afa7-4aab5370cbec"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="170" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="b5a72533-c1b6-4af9-a0b7-06d099981190"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{filed1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="300" y="0" width="90" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="bab5a3e9-22db-46b0-9302-f7614a6f6add"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Parameter1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d4338fad-1803-491e-90ef-8e01cb3de80d"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="170" y="0" width="130" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="8cdac468-0a3f-4ed3-844b-473e1371f92e"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="120" y="0" width="50" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6ab2f4f8-04cd-4a6f-b945-3a7af4b8c3fa"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Finally solution solved. Thanks @dada67 for detail answer.

**Solution 1:**
you can create jasperreports.properties file on your classpath and add the below line to this file:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.consume.space.on.overflow=falsenet.sf.jasperreports.consume.space.on.overflow=false
```

**Solution 2:**
you can set this value programmatically also

```
DefaultJasperReportsContext djrc = net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.getI‌​nstance();
djrc.setProperty(net.sf.jaspe‌​rreports.engine.fill‌​.JRFillTextElement.P‌​ROPERTY_CONSUME_SPAC‌​E_ON_OVERFLOW,
                    Boolean.toString(false));
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then post the JRXML.

Comment: @DaveJarvis please check it. I added sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're describing seems to be the same as http://community.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer/issues/8146

According to the comments, the upcoming release (6.3.1) will fix the issue.

In the meantime you can set the following property in your jasperreports.properties to avoid the problem:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.consume.space.on.overflow=false
```

Comment: Thanks for more detail and links.

Comment: where should I put jasper.properties file?

Comment: jasperreports.properties needs to be placed in a folder which is part of the application classpath (e.g. WEB-INF/classes in a web application).

Comment: I put but does not help. maybe i put in wrong folder

Comment: If you're unsure about your application's classpath, you can set the property programmatically by doing net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.PROPERTY_CONSUME_SPACE_ON_OVERFLOW, Boolean.toString(true))

Comment: Should I set this value false or true to avoid this kind of problem. Because your first comment set to false but on your last comment set to true

Comment: Thank you very much. Now problem is solved correct value is: false.